# Redirect a route in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, routes

Im building an API in Laravel 5.3. In my `routes/api.php` file I have 3 endpoints:

```
Route::post('/notify/v1/notifications', 'Api\Notify\v1\NotifyApiController@notificationsPost');

Route::post('/notify/v1/alerts', 'Api\Notify\v1\NotifyApiController@alertsPost');

Route::post('/notify/v1/incidents', 'Api\Notify\v1\NotifyApiController@incidentsPost');
```

Several services will call these routes directly, however, when a request comes in from some services, the input data needs to be processed before it can hit these endpoints.

For example, if a request comes in from JIRA, I need to process the input before it hits these endpoints.

Im thinking that the simplest way to do this would be to have a 4th endpoint like the below:

```
Route::post('/notify/v1/jira', 'Api\Notify\v1\JiraFormatter@formatJiraPost');
```

The idea being to hit the `/notify/v1/jira` endpoint, have the `formatJiraPost` method process the input and then forward the request to `/notify/v1/notifications (/alerts, /incidents)` as required.

**How can I have the `/notify/v1/jira` endpoint forward the request to the `/notify/v1/notifications` endpoint?**

**Do you see a better way to do this?**

Comment: You can use middleware to format your request data and then forward it to the same endpoint without the need of a 4th one.

Comment: Agree with @TheFallen. Using a middleware to check for "Pre Processing Requirements" could be your better option. Although, one thing to consider is wrapping all 3 endpoints inside a middleware could add some execution time overhead. Due to the "checking all requests" to see if they need pre processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending how your app will work, you could always have your services pointing to `/notify/v1/jira` and then do the processing like you suggested.

Another alternative is have the JIRA service pointing at the same routes as all the other services but to use a [Before middleware group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#middleware-groups) to pre-process your data. Something like

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['verifyService']], function () {

    Route::post('/notify/v1/notifications', 'Api\Notify\v1\NotifyApiController@notificationsPost');

    Route::post('/notify/v1/alerts', 'Api\Notify\v1\NotifyApiController@alertsPost');

    Route::post('/notify/v1/incidents', 'Api\Notify\v1\NotifyApiController@incidentsPost');

});
```

You could check in your middleware your service.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class verifyService
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {  
        //You could use switch/break case structure
        if (isJIRA($request)) {

            //Do some processing, it could be outsourced to another class
            //$JiraPost = new formatJiraPost($request);

            //Keep the requesting going to the routes with processed data
            return $next($request);
        }

        //You could add extra logic to check for more services.

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function isJIRA(Request $request){
       //Logic to check if it is JIRA.
    }
}
```